# ansible: create user without asking runner's password

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I have the following two ymls:

```yml
---

- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - username: test
  tasks:
    - name: Include User
      include: 'user.yml'
      become: true
```

```yml
---

- name: Create user '{{ username }}'
  user:
    name: '{{ username }}'
    password: 'password...'
    become: true
```

I got the error message below:

```sh
$ ansible-playbook main.yml
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}
```

I do not want to pass my password during the execution.
Is it possible to run the script without asking password from the executor?

If so, how can I alter the ansible descriptor accordingly?

Ansible 2.6.1
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

You have several options

You can set `NOPASSwD` for your user in `/etc/sudoers`, I would not consider this secure

`superuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL`

Another option would be to set a variable `ansible_sudo_pass` in your your inventory, `host_vars` or `group_vars`. You should create a vault for it, not to store the password in clear text, to make it secure, but you will have to enter a vault password then.